# Como registrar uma DLL no sistema?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho uma DLL que não consigo registrar no sistema.

Se eu pego a DLL original, ela é registrada, porem se eu pego a que foi gerada na máquina da empresa, ela registra. Não sei se eu tenho que fazer alguma coisa.

Para registrar no sistema(W7 64bits), faço assim:

> C>regsvr32 GenQuickRpt001.dll

Após ter colocado a DLL no System32 do windows, tenho essa mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se coloco a dll no SysWOW64, dá essa outra mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que existe uma forma de fazer o registro pelo Delphi, quando se trabalha com DLL.

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: tenta o seguinte: C:\%windir%\SysWow64\regsvr32 GenQuickRpt001.dll

Comment: @cantoni, continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você já tentou rodar o comando de dentro de um prompt como "Administrador"? [Esta página](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873) mostra algumas soluções para este tipo de problema

Comment: @Gomiero, não roda por nada, não consigo instalar. Mas a DLL original, eu consigo instalar. Deve haver alguma restrição na hora de compilar, que pode estar impedindo o registro. Nada foi alterado, isso posso garantir dos fontes originais. Mas se rodar na máquina do colega, fica dando esse pau. O que pode impedir?

Answer (score 2):

Duas coisas, para registrar uma DLL de 32 bits você usa o regsvr32 e para as DLL de 64 bits você usa o regsvr32, como o nome é o mesmo você deve atentar à pasta de instalação de cada um!

Se você recebe um erro ao registrar um DLL de 32 bits em uma versão de 64 bits do Windows, siga estas etapas:

1. Abra um prompt de comando com privilégios elevados.
2. Se a DLL de 32 bits estiver na pasta *%systemroot%\System32*, mova-a para a pasta *%systemroot%\SysWoW64*.
3. Execute o seguinte comando: `%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 <caminho completo da DLL>`

[Fonte!](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/249873)

[Relacionado com varias possíveis soluções!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit)